# MYSQL select display matching and non matching records

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a list of strings all separated by a new line. I need to match these strings with the value in a column in one single table. The problem is I need to display non-matching records as a defined value, example "not found" so the output remains the same length as the input and the results all remain in the same order.

**Example Input**

1. apple
2. orange
3. pear
4. banana

**Desired Output**

1. apple exists
2. orange not found
3. pear exists
4. banana exists

Is it possible to assign a custom value to records not found as well as display records found in a single statement?
Info seems to suggest I can create a statement using IFNULL to return non-matching records, I have experimented with this but to no avail.

```
 <?php
 // Wrap strings for select statement
 $strings = $_POST['mystrings'];
 $regex = '~<[^>]+>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\b\w+\b~'; 
 $strings_wrapped = preg_replace($regex, "'\\0',", $strings);
 $strings_prepared = substr($strings_wrapped, 0, -1);

 // Statement
 $select = "select * from table where specific_row in ($strings_prepared)";

 // Connect
 $connect = mysqli_query($con, $select);

      // Retrieve rows
      while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($connect)) {
      $column1 = $row['column1'];
      $column2 = $row['column2'];
      $column3 = $row['column3'];
      $column4 = $row['column4'];
      $column5 = $row['column5'];

      // Display results
      $results = "$column1-$column2-$column3-$column4-$column5\n";
      echo $results;
      }
 ?>
```

The matching rows are returned without error. I just don't know how to display the non-matching rows as well.

Comment: Iterate over input and see if it exists in rows.

Comment: @u_mulder I'm getting plenty of results for matching rows but I need to also display the ones which don't match.

Comment: Do you have all inputs? Iterate over them and __check__ if they are found in results of query.

Comment: @u_mulder I think I know what you mean. I'll do a test and come back. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

This is the approach you can use:

```
// Statement
$select = "select * from table where specific_row in ($strings_prepared)";
// Connect
$connect = mysqli_query($con, $select);

// Retrieve rows
$founded = [];
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($connect)) {
    $founded[$row['specific_row']] = $row['column1'];  // or whatever
}

foreach ($strings_prepared as $string) {
    if (!empty($founded[$string])) {
        echo 'found';
    } else {
        echo 'NOT found';
    }
}
```

Comment: I exhausted attempts using this example and multiple variations. It doesn't work as the original select statement is limiting the results to the specific set of strings inputted. The solution has to lie in altering the select statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery to create a derived table containing the names you want to search for, and join that with the table.

```
SELECT a.value, IF(b.specific_row IS NULL, 'not found', 'exists') AS found
FROM (
    SELECT 'apple' AS value
    UNION
    SELECT 'orange'
    UNION
    SELECT 'pear'
    UNION
    SELECT 'banana'
) AS a
LEFT JOIN table AS b ON a.value = b.specific_row
```

Comment: I'm struggling with this as the code I showed requires a where in clause as part of the select. I'm not sure how to implement that to your example. I probably shouldn't have included the simplistic example before the main code, my fault.

Comment: Put the condition in the `ON` clause.